# APscheduler wait till previous job is finished

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, scheduler, apscheduler

I'm triyng to orderly schedule jobs, but I want only 1 job running at a time

```
from time import sleep
from random import random
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import wait
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler,BackgroundScheduler

def real_task1(i):
    print(f'running {i}')
    sleep(3)
    print(f'finished {i}')

def real_task2(i):
    print(f'running 2 {i}')
    sleep(3)
    print(f'finished 2 {i}')

def real_task3(i):
    print(f'running 3 {i}')
    sleep(3)
    print(f'finished 3 {i}')

def task1():
    # start the process pool
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # submit tasks and collect futures
        pairs = ['hi','ho','hu']
        futures = [executor.submit(real_task1, i) for i in pairs]
        # wait for all tasks to complete
        print('Waiting for tasks to complete1...')
        wait(futures)
        print('All tasks are done1!')

def task2():
    # start the process pool
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # submit tasks and collect futures
        pairs = ['hi','ho','hu']
        futures = [executor.submit(real_task2, i) for i in pairs]
        # wait for all tasks to complete
        print('Waiting for tasks to complete2...')
        wait(futures)
        print('All tasks are done2!')

def task3():
    # start the process pool
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # submit tasks and collect futures
        pairs = ['hi','ho','hu']
        futures = [executor.submit(real_task3, i) for i in pairs]
        # wait for all tasks to complete
        print('Waiting for tasks to complete3...')
        wait(futures)
        print('All tasks are done3!')

 
# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Creates a default Background Scheduler
    #call the task funcs in a scheduled time
    sched = BlockingScheduler()
    #sched = BackgroundScheduler()
    sched.add_job(task1, 'cron', day_of_week= 'mon-fri', hour= '*',
                           minute= '*', second = 0)#end_date= '2022-06-30',args= ['job 5']
    sched.add_job(task2, 'cron', day_of_week= 'mon-fri', hour= '*',
                           minute= '*', second = 1)#end_date= '2022-06-30',args= ['job 5']
    sched.add_job(task3, 'cron', day_of_week= 'mon-fri', hour= '*',
                           minute= '*', second = 2)#end_date= '2022-06-30',args= ['job 5']
    
    sched.start()
    beg = datetime.now()

    #sched.run_pending()

    sched.shutdown()
    end = datetime.now()
    print(f'shutted down schedule, duration {end-beg}')
```

this almost produces expected return, but is starting 2 jobs at a time:

```
Waiting for tasks to complete1... Waiting for tasks to complete2...
running hi running ho running hu Waiting for tasks to complete3...
running 2 hi running 2 ho running 2 hu running 3 hi running 3 ho
running 3 hu finished hi finished ho finished hu All tasks are done1!
finished 2 hi finished 2 ho finished 2 hu All tasks are done2!
finished 3 hi finished 3 ho finished 3 hu All tasks are done3!
```